# How can I create a 50/50 vertical layout with stacked GridViews?

Tags: android, gridview

One of my DialogFragments implements two equal-sized GridViews, one stacked on top of the other. Ideally, my layout would look like this (as seen in Android Studio):
[image: The layout as seen in Android Studio]

Unfortunately, when I load up the layout on an actual Android device, I get something like this:
[image: The same layout on Android]

When the **Kanji** GridView is empty, it's completely invisible. Additionally, its height varies depending on the number of elements it has to display. How can I force the bottom GridView to fill 50% of the height as per the layout seen in Android Studio, even when it's empty?

Here is the XML for this particular layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/kanji_lookup_root"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/search_box_kanji"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@id/search_box_kanji"
            android:queryHint="@string/menu_search_hint"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/EntryDetailsHeader"
            android:text="@string/components" />

        <com.tonicartos.widget.stickygridheaders.StickyGridHeadersGridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_components"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="9"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            style="@style/EntryDetailsHeader"
            android:text="@string/kanji" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_kanji"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="9"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

(By the way I'm using the [StickyGridHeaders library](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) for the upper **Components** GridView)

Answer (score 0):

Change the '0dp' layout_height on your two LinearLayouts to 'match_parent'.

Comment: No dice, I tried that and the bottom LinearLayout still disappears if there's nothing in the child GridView. I just want it to fill its designated spot regardless of the number of items in the GridView. :\

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `weightSum` attribute on your outermost `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/kanji_lookup_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:weightSum="2" > <!-- This line is what you were missing -->
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Tested this as working on device (assuming your EntryDetailsHeader style sets `match_parent` width and `wrap_content` height).

Comment: This is what I'm seeing, with your code + the weightSum modification: http://i.imgur.com/01niMY6.png

Comment: Okay, so, to make things even more confusing the layout works fine if I transplant the code from my DialogFragment into a new FragmentActivity. This potentially points to a bug in the Fragment class (and its derivatives) that prevents the weight from being respected on that second GridView.